# How to retrieve VsTest Test Plan test case id during Azure pipeline is running and use that in automation code

Tags: azure, azure-devops, vstest

Use Case:

- Define a Test Plan, Test Suite and add test cases to it on ADO.
- Link multiple (all) the tests on Test Plan to a single MsTest method.
- Azure pipeline is setup to run the automation suite using the “Visual Studio Test” task and “Select tests using” option is set as “Test Plan”

I am searching for a solution on when Azure pipeline starts and VsTest task is running, can we get the Test case ID/Name (from ADO Test Plan) which is currently processed to run and provide that ID/Name to automation test method (as a parameter option to MsTest test). Using that test case ID, I will run few control statements in the code to perform desired tasks.

But, everything should happen runtime and the approach should be dynamic. Also, it should support parallel test execution.

Could you please share your thoughts.

TIA.
Akshay J.

Comment: Hi Akshay J, I am glad that my answer works for you. You could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this case, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

> > Azure pipeline is setup to run the automation suite using the “Visual Studio Test” task and “Select tests using” option is set as “Test Plan”

According to your description, so [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) is configured like below.
[image]

In that case, you will know the id of test plan and id of test suite, so you could use Rest API: [Test Suites - Get Test Cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get all test cases in a suite including `id` and `url`, and then request this `url` will get `fields.System.Title`, that is the name of test case.

BTW, you could use API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get this release definition, in the response you will find the following VsTest task and its settings including id of test plan and id of test suite.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Edward, 
I tried this option and able to get the Test Plan,Suite,cases details.
But, is there a way I could get the exact test case ID which the Azure pipeline is running at a given point of time by using any logs or additional scripts.
I have a single automation script written is MsTest which reads YAML file based on this TC ID and performs necessary assertions. I want the automation code run in a controlled way for all the underline tests when selected the Test Plan option on Azure pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am glad that my answer works for you. You could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Comment: For your further question, currently Azure pipeline will output task log when this task is completed, so we cannot get logs which the Azure pipeline is running at a given point of time. You could submit this suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion, the product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.